# Google Analytics data processing timezone

Tags: google-analytics

Which timezone use Google Analytics to process analytics data?
I know that the processing latency is 24-48 hours but I don't understand how to calculate when my data will be available.

Thanks

Comment: Come to think of it this is not about programming (but configuration), so it's probably off-topic.

Comment: I think it's relevant, especially if your data isn't going to be processed in UTC for dumb reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Google Evangelist Justin Cutroni](http://cutroni.com/blog/2014/04/02/universal-analytics-now-beta/) (written 2014/04/02):

> In addition to the above features, there’s one more piece that is
>   rolling out today. Google Analytics users can now specify the
>   time-zone where their data is processed. In the past all data was
>   processed in the Pacific Timezone (because that’s there Google is).

Comment: Eike, do you know if this is related to Analytics data in BigQuery as well?